# What does colon mean in Perl?

Tags: perl, syntax

What does the colon mean in the following Perl program?

```
MAIN: {
    print "Hello\n";
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to this question, but for readers who come here through the title: colon can also be used for [calling method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30982697/use-of-colon-in-method-and-function-calls-in-perl-6).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It separates a label (`MAIN`) from a block (the stuff between curly braces).

In Perl, a label is always suffixed with a colon, so you might argue the colon is part of the label.

Comment: Thanks all upvoters: you've earned me the "Enlightened" badge! :-D

Comment: "...you might argue the colon is part of the label," except that you don't use a colon when you refer to the label.  For example, it's `redo MAIN;` not `redo MAIN:;`, so it's not a very good argument.

Comment: Ok, let's argue its part of the "labeling" then. FWIW, I personally don't think it's a great argument either, but the wording of the questions kind of begged for it.

Comment: And now I've read DVK's answer, it makes that (won't say "my") point even more valid: "The LABEL [...] consists of an identifier followed by a colon." No ambiguity.

Answer (score 11):

The colon is a required separator of a label from the following block.

From [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html):

> The LABEL is optional, and if present, consists of an identifier followed by a colon