# Perl 6 function argument syntax in the interpreter (REPL)

Tags: function, arguments, raku

There seems to be some inconsistencies in the argument syntax in the interpreter. I am using the latest Rakudo. Please see the following terminal output:

```
$ perl6
To exit type 'exit' or '^D'
> say: "foo"
foo
> say("foo")
foo
> say "foo"
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling:
Two terms in a row
------> say⏏ "foo"
    expecting any of:
        infix
        infix stopper
        statement end
        statement modifier
        statement modifier loop
> 
$ perl6
To exit type 'exit' or '^D'
> say "foo"
foo
> say("foo")
foo
> say: "foo"
foo
> say "foo"
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling:
Two terms in a row
------> say⏏ "foo"
    expecting any of:
        infix
        infix stopper
        statement end
        statement modifier
        statement modifier loop
> 
$
```

It seems that after you have used the "`:`" or "`()`" to supply the arguments, you cannot go back to use "", i.e., space, to supply arguments.

Or did I miss something?

Thanks !!!

lisprog

Comment: I made a similar mistake before (see [Use of colon in method and function calls in Perl 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30982697/use-of-colon-in-method-and-function-calls-in-perl-6))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> `say: "foo"`

That line does **not** call the `say` subroutine.

Instead, it declares a [statement label](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Label) with the name `say`, and then executes the statement `"foo"` (which does nothing).

The only reason it printed `"foo"` in your case, is because you entered it into the REPL, which automatically prints the value of the last statement of each line.

If you had used it in a normal program, it would have actually thrown the warning `Useless use of constant string "foo" in sink context`.

> `say "foo"
>   ===SORRY!=== Error while compiling:
>   Two terms in a row
>   ------> say⏏ "foo"
>       expecting any of:
>           infix
>           infix stopper
>           statement end
>           statement modifier
>           statement modifier loop`

After you've declared the label, the symbol `say` in this scope no longer refers to the built-in subroutine with that name but rather to your custom label, and it is a syntax error to use a label like that.

The error message should ideally explain that, though. I've [submitted a Rakudo ticket](https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=131754) for that.

Comment: I see ! Thank you smls !! Always something

Comment: Sorry smls: just one more questions. If say: "foo" creates a label, then how about this syntax in the perl6 documentation, https://docs.perl6.org/routine/map , where you see a ":" after the method map ---> say ('hello', 1, 22/7, 42, 'world').map: { .WHAT.perl } # OUTPUT: «(Str Int Rat Int Str)␤»  ; I was trying the same syntax as map. How to distinguish ":" as label  from ":" as a way to call an argument? Thanks.

Comment: @lisprogtor: It's only a label declaration when there's a word followed by a colon **directly at the beginning of a statement** (not counting whitespace).

Comment: @lisprogtor: The colon-form for method calls doesn't exist for subroutine calls, because they already have an even simpler parenthesis-less form: `say 42`